# How to localize date picker calendar based on country/region?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, typescript, datepicker

I am working on html web page to get user detail. User first enters country and then selects date using date picker. I have used the following code using date picker.

```
protected SetDate(id: string) {
     $("#SomeID").datepicker({
     dayNames: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
     monthNames: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
     // In japanese
     monthNamesShort: ["一月", "二月", "三月", "四月", "五月", "六月", "七月", "八月", "九月", "十月", "十一月", "十二月"],
     dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
        });
    }
```

How can I localize date picker calendar as per user selected the country or using TS code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Datepicker plugin does exactly what you want if I understood correctly.

You have an exemple here => [DatePicker Localization Documentation](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization)

[More detailed documentation about localization](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)